# Execution was interrupted, EXC Bad Instruction on func call with params - Swift iOS

Tags: swift

Trying to do a binary search in swift , i am seeing the below exc bad instruction can any one please help what could be wrong in below code.

```
import UIKit

let numberList : Array<Int> = [1,3,4,6,7,10,12,14,17,18,20,23,25,55,56,60,67]

numberList.count

/* Binary Search */

func binarySearch(sequence:Array<Int>,key:Int) -> Int{

  //get first index, Mid index and Max index of array
  //start index would be zero

  var startIndex = 0
  var midIndex = (startIndex + sequence.count) / 2
  var maxIndex = sequence.count-1

  print(midIndex)

  if key > numberList[midIndex] {

    print("key found after midIndex")

  }

  if key < numberList[midIndex] {

    print("key found before midIndex")
    var slice = Array(sequence[maxIndex...midIndex-1])
    print(slice)
    //binarySearch(sequence,key)

  }

  return key
}

//binarySearch(numberList, key: 10)
binarySearch(numberList, key: 10) //error on this line :- exc bad instruction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in your call but in the implementation of your function.

```
var slice = Array(sequence[maxIndex...midIndex-1])
```

must be

```
var slice = Array(sequence[midIndex-1...maxIndex])
```

cause maxIndex is greater than midIndex-1